# Неравномерный сдвиг окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать растягивание повсеместно и "адекватно"?[image]
(чтобы и элементы увеличивались)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не задавать напрямую размеры компонентов. используй margin. ваще не плохо бы было добавить xaml код

Comment: Обычно для этого пользуются layout manager'ом, и не задают размеры в пикселях, а позицию маргинами.